# How do I check how many seconds since the chatbot is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, chatbot

My html code like this :

```
<div class="chatbot chatbot--closed ">
  <div class="chatbot__header">
    <p><strong>Got a question?</strong> <span class="u-text-highlight">Ask Harry</span></p>
    <svg class="chatbot__close-button icon-speech" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <use xlink:href="#icon-speech" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="chatbot__close-button icon-close" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <use xlink:href="#icon-close"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="chatbot__message-window">
    <ul class="chatbot__messages">
      <li class="is-ai animation">
        <div class="is-ai__profile-picture">
          <svg class="icon-avatar" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
            <use xlink:href="#avatar" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <span class="chatbot__arrow chatbot__arrow--left"></span>
        <p class='chatbot__message'><strong class='intro'>Hello, I’m Harry, your virtual assistant. I'm here to help with your general enquiries.</strong>Example of questions you can ask for demo purpose: <br><em>Hi / How are you? / I'd like some financial advice / Can you email me a statement? / Can I get a form? /  How do I cancel my life insurance? </em></p>
      </li>
      <!-- Message here -->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="chatbot__entry chatbot--closed">
    <input type="text" class="chatbot__input" placeholder="Write a message..." />
    <svg class="chatbot__submit" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <use xlink:href="#icon-send" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo and full code like this : https://codepen.io/trendingnews/pen/wvBorrR?editors=1010

When the user clicks close on the chatbot, it will appear a feedback modal to fill the user experience using chatbot. I want this feedback modal to appear when the chatbot has been open for about 30 seconds. So if the chatbot has been open for more than 30 seconds and the user clicks close, modal feedback appears. But if the chatbot hasn't been open for 30 seconds, the user clicks close to chatbot, the modal doesn't appear

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to navigate in your code but I will provide guidelines:

When the chatbot is open, assign a value to a variable "showModal" to false. Then create a timeout that executes after 30seconds and sets this variable to true.

```
// global scope variables
var showModal = false;
var timeoutId;

// code for opening chatbot
function openChatbotHandler() {
    // do some cleaning first
    if(timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }

    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        showModal = true;
    }, 30000)
}
```

When the chatbot is closed, simple check for the value of the variable "showModal". If its false then don't open a modal, if its true open a modal.

```
// code for closing chatbot
function closeChatbotHandler() {
    // do some cleaning first
    if(timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }

    if(showModal) {
        // reset it for next time around
        showModal = false; 


        // code for opening your modal
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try that first. Btw, I want to ask again. Can feedback be displayed when the user closes the browser or clicks other elements outside the chatbot? For example if it's been 30 seconds, user click another element/close browser, it will appear the feedback modal?

Comment: If you close browser then you lose your memory and with it the variables stored.

Comment: so it can't show the feedback modal if the user closes the browser?

Comment: Hi. I want to ask last question. How do I add a trigger to close chatbot if the user clicks outside of chatbot?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $chatbotHeader.addEventListener("click", () => {
     var element = document.getElementsByClassName("chatbot");
     element[0].style.display = "none";
     showModal.chatClose = performance.now(); // Sets when chat gets open
     showModal();
     document.getElementById("chat-circle").style.display="block";
  },false);

 document.getElementById("chat-circle").addEventListener( "click", () => {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("chatbot");
    element[0].classList.remove("chatbot--closed");
    element[0].style.display = "block";
    showModal.chatOpen = performance.now(); //Sets when chat window is closed
    $chatbotInput.focus();
    console.log(this);
    document.getElementById("chat-circle").style.display="none";   
   }
 );

 function showModal() {
   if( showModal.chatClose - showModal.chatOpen > 1800) {
      alert("show Modal"); // Code to show modal here 
   }
   showModal.chatClose = showModal.chatOpen = 0;
 }
```

Comment: the start time is calculated when the chatbot opens. so when the chatbot isn't open, time isn't counted

Comment: Yes, I am setting the chatOpen value when the chat-cirle is clicked and after the chat window is visible. (element[0].style.display)

Comment: I had implement your code into my codepen. When I open the codepen first time. I waiting 30 second and I open the chatbot and close chatbot, it show modal. Should if I open chatbot and close, it can not. It must waiting 30 second after chatbot open

Comment: @SuccessMan I am sorry, I did not quiet understand what you were saying. Is it working now? If not  what's the error you are seeing.

Comment: I want to ask question. How do I add a trigger to close chatbot if the user clicks outside of chatbot?